# Inserting small table of content looks terrible

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I'd like to add a small table of content inside my file.
I want to place it right after the abstract and make "Introduccion" start on the next page.
However it places it at the beginning and looks terrible.
I also want to change its color to red and the "Contents" table to "Index" or something else.
Here's the first part of my code:

```
\documentclass[JDR,PDF]{jdr} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/\detokenize{#1}}{doi: \detokenize{#1}}}
\newenvironment{myproof}[2] {\paragraph{Proof of {#1} {#2}:}}{\hfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(400,8){\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{zabbix_logo.png}}
\end{picture}

\title{Zabbix: Sistema de Monitoreo y Alertas}

\articletype{How-To} % Original Article, Review Article, Communication, Erratum


\author{
Grupo 3
}

\institute{
         x
}


\abstract{Es una solución open source de monitoreo. Permite monitorear diversos parámetros de una red así como la salud e integridad de servidores. Mediante un sistema de notificaciones es posible la configuración de alertas por mail. Tiene funcionalidades para visualizar datos y obtener reportes. }

{\small\tableofcontents}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%Introduction%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introducción}

En este documento se detalla un ejemplo de implementación de Zabbix....
```

Here's my [CLS (it's a template)](https://pastebin.com/C0wu9dE6).

[image]

Comment: your example does not compile on my side even with the class and logo files. A problem with the xcolorpackage...

Comment: mmm I get warnings on overleaf regarding xcolor but I'm not even using that package.